What is fragmentation scale in particle physics?
This is a quick guestion. What is used as the fragmentation scale in cross section calculations? If I have a quark which hadronizes, is the fragmentation scale (at which the fragmentation function is taken) the mass of the quark or maybe the CMS energy of the collision? I haven't found an answer to this from the web.
